# CTE, why is an empty table returned?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using a Postgresql database and I'm trying to get a tree using a CTE:

```
Alice
...Bob
......Dave
......Emma
...Cindy
......Fred
......Gail
```

Doesn't output any errors. There is nothing in the output, where did I go wrong?

Database

```
CREATE TABLE org(
  name TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
  boss TEXT REFERENCES org
);

INSERT INTO org VALUES('Alice',NULL);
INSERT INTO org VALUES('Bob','Alice');
INSERT INTO org VALUES('Cindy','Alice');
INSERT INTO org VALUES('Dave','Bob');
INSERT INTO org VALUES('Emma','Bob');
INSERT INTO org VALUES('Fred','Cindy');
INSERT INTO org VALUES('Gail','Cindy');
```

My request:

```
WITH RECURSIVE under_alice AS (select name, boss, 0 AS level FROM org 
     where boss = null
    UNION ALL
    SELECT org.name, org.boss, under_alice.level+1
      FROM org JOIN under_alice ON org.boss=under_alice.name
  )
SELECT * FROM under_alice;
```

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using (MySQL, Postgres, Oracle, SQL Server, something else)? Please add the tag of your database to your question. See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) to know why tagging is important.

Comment: `IS NULL`, not `= NULL`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WITH RECURSIVE under_alice AS
(
  select name, boss, 0 AS level FROM org 
     where boss IS NULL 
 UNION ALL
  SELECT org.name, org.boss, under_alice.level+1
  FROM org JOIN under_alice ON org.boss=under_alice.name
)
SELECT * FROM under_alice
```

Please take a look on  where boss IS NULL. Here is the issue in your query